# Can You Switch Between Actual Expenses and Per Diem Expensing For Meals / Entertainment?

Tags: united-states, taxes, expenses, business

I currently report the actual costs for my meals and entertainment expenses on business trips.  I am thinking about switching over to the Per Diem method.

Are there any regulations against using both in a single calendar year?  If so, what are the guardrails to follow?  I am operating as a S-Corp.

Comment: Is this a trip you take to benefit your employer? or a trip for a government contract?

Comment: Report to whom? Are you asking about tax deductions, or employer reimbursements?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep This is for business expense deductions from an employer's perpsectie